# How to switch to new user from MySQL console

Tags: mysql

Im having a little problem in using mysql on windows. I know how to create a new user and giving grants to the new user and all. But i don't know how to switch to new user from mysql console!

Comment: What interface are you using? (i.e., is it command-line, something web-based, etc.)

Answer (score 6):

You have to exit and log in again using the new username.

From shell:

```
mysql --user=user_name --password=your_password db_name
```

Reference:

- http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,247384,247391#msg-247391
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/mysql.html

Comment: Hey guys!! I got the solution to my problem. when we open mysql through mysql console of wampserver it directly logs in as root. So what I did was I logged in through command prompt and it worked. 

" E:\InstalledFiles\MySql\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin "

This is where my mysql.exe file is. So I went till bin and gave this command in the command prompt

"  mysql -u root -p  "

So I could login as root from command prompt. The same way you can log in as a different user if You have created one .

Comment: Glad to hear that. I assumed you were already logging in from command prompt. Surely you can change the user and password with which you log in from any program. The point is that connection is made for one specific user, so you cannot change the user and keep the connection, you have to (close first connection if you are not going to use it anymore and) open new connection for the new user.

Answer (score 4):

Once you have your new user created, try changing your default shortcut to log in as that user directly instead.

Go to Start Menu > MySql x.x Command Line Client > right-clicked > Properties > Target and changed the user (from `-uroot`) to `-uyournewuser`:

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysql.exe" "--defaults-file=C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini" "-uroot" "-p"
```

Comment: Note, as posted in comments below by Sunil, this actually would have fixed the OP's problem!! :) Good job, gtinker!